# Javascript maximize / unmaximize window with same button

Tags: javascript, html, node-webkit

hello, I am a beginner in HTML5 / JS. 
I want to enlarge and restore a window with the same Boutton javascript. 
Some could help me please?

I work with webkit node.

Here are the two buttons I want to combine into one.

```
<button onclick="win.maximize()"> Maximize </ button> 

<button onclick="win.unmaximize()"> Unmaximize </ button>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You can't maximize a window through javascript. Could do fullscreen though. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Using_full_screen_mode

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<script>
var isMaximized = true;

function main(){
   if (isMaximized){
      isMaximized = false;
      win.unmaximize();
   }else{
      isMaximized = true;
      win.maximize();
   }
}
</script>

<button onclick="main()"> Maximize </ button>
```

You can also change the label of the button thanks to this function.

Comment: thank you it works but I have a little problem. must first Double click the first time for it to work.

Comment: @user2923215 try to set `isMaximized` at `false` instead of `true`